# Using recursion on sequence of mathematical numbers?

Tags: python, math, recursion

I want to use recursion on continuous fractions, which will go like this.

The user will input a value of n, and if n is 3, then it will go like this:

2 + 1/ (1 + 1 / (2 + 2/ (3 + 3 / 4)))

where the first 2 + 1/ are fixed in the equation, now we have to calculate the numbers behind it. That is the part where i have been scratching my head for days. Someone taught me that it is possible to use recursion to calculate that part, but I have been trying to learn how to use it but mine just loops forever or has a recursionError

```
n = int(input("Enter n value: "))
result = 0
fract = 0

def frac(j):
    global fract
    for i in range(j):
        fract = (j + j)/ frac(j)
    return fract

def calc_e():
    e = 2 + 1/ frac(n) / n + 1
    return e

print(calc_e())

#formula = 2 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (2 + 2 / (3 + 3 / (4 + 4 / (...)))))
```

TLDR: I dont know how to calculate the part after 2 + 1/

Comment: Here's a hint: What is the base function you are trying to recurse? To me it seems like `n + n/(n+1)`. You are on the right track with your code, see if you can fix it. If you still stuck I (or another SO-er) would be glad to point you in the right direction

Comment: yeap i am stuck confirmed. Tried changing the function in any way i can think of. I have changed it to (j + j) / fract(j), replaced the for loop with an if statement, and tried using temporary variables to make it start dividing from 1. All of gives out errors or the wrong answers

Comment: Have the given answers helped you?

Comment: yeap the answers here are really helpful! I've only have like 20 mins of recursive knowledge from school and this post helped me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use a `global` variable; I don't see where the need for a `for`-loop arises either. And as previous answers have pointed out, you have a few algebra mistakes.

You should add a stopping condition argument to `frac` to stop it from infinitely recursing. Return the value `j` if this is hit:

```
# max number of terms n
def frac(j, n):
    if j >= n: return n
    return j + j / frac(j+1, n)

# remember to pass 1.0 instead of 1, or cast to float in frac
# to avoid integer division which will truncate all fractions
def calc_e(n=100):
    return 2 + 1 / frac(1.0, n)
```

This returns:

```
n    calc_e(n)
----------------------
2    2.666666666666667
4    2.716981132075472
8    2.718281657666404
16   2.718281828459045
32   2.718281828459046
64   2.718281828459046
128  2.718281828459046
256  2.718281828459046
512  2.718281828459046
```

A higher number of recursions was not possible due to stack overflow.

Comment: Ah now it looks familiar to the code my tutor taught me. Though now you posted the full solution on S/O i cant use it due to plagiarism anymore lol. Thanks though this helped me understand recursion better

Comment: @bluelighty ah yes about that ... you could implement my other suggestion of casting to `float` instead of passing 1.0 (see in-code comments), as a way of circumventing the plagiarism checks

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple recursion:

```
#2 + 1/ (1 + 1 / (2 + 2/ (3 + 3 / 4)))
def get_equation(_to_val, string_rep = False):
   if string_rep:
     def calculate(start, end):
       return '{}+{}/({})'.format(start, start, calculate(start+1, end) if start < end else end+1)
     return '2+1/({})'.format(calculate(1, _to_val))
   def calculate(start, end):
      return start+start/(calculate(start+1, end) if start < end else end+1)
   return calculate(1, _to_val)


print(get_equation(3))
print(get_equation(3, True))
```

Output:

```
1.3947368421052633
2+1/(1+1/(2+2/(3+3/(4))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some basic problems in your `frac` routine

```
def frac(j):
    global fract
    for i in range(j):
        fract = (j + j)/ frac(j)
    return fract
```

- You haven't settled on how to communicate the result: you keep updating the global `fract`, but returning its value afterward.  Only one of these should be necessary.
- Similarly, you are stepping through the continued fraction with *both* a `for` loop *and* recursion.  You should use only one of these.
- You have no *base case* on your recursion: there's nothing to tell the algorithm that it has "hit bottom".  Every time you hit the computation step, you recur on `frac`; there's no logic path that does *not* recur.  This is the main reason you get infinite recursion.  If these are new concepts for you, please work through a tutorial on recursion; that will explain it at least as well as we can here.
- Your algebra is wrong: `(j + j)/ frac(j)` is the wrong order of operations, and gives you merely `2*j / frac(j)`.  You should have something like `j + j/frac(j+1)`.

Is that enough hints to get you to a more useful coding practice?  You may also need help debugging; a few well-chosen `print` statements will usually show you what's happening.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: Ive tried changing the code around in function frac(j), but somehow still cannot get it to work. I have replaced the for loop with an if statement, and fixed the algebra. But now I don't know when to return values in recursion, and also how to get j to start from 1?

Comment: Good: you've identified the basic techniques in which you're weak.  Search for those phrases and work through at least one tutorial on each topic: loops, functions, and recursion.  Each of these will sink in much better through a full tutorial; that level of wide-ranging assistance is off topic for Stack Overflow.